# Are system framework leaks my fault / preventable in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, memory-management, memory-leaks

This is a bit of a general question, I am debugging and testing on the iPhone and the leaks performance tool is reporting a ton of relatively small leaks from code that I didn't write. I.e. in the responsible frame column the following are blamed for leaks:

`[UIColor allocWithZone:]

NSKeyedUnarchiver

NSCFString copyWithZone

CGTypeCreateInstanceWithAllocator

UIView _createLayerWithFrame:

mem_alloc`

The responsible libraries are mainly Foundation, with a couple from UIKit and CoreGraphics, and the mem_alloc leak is blamed on QuartzCore.

They add up to about 40KB after 10 minutes of touching buttons at random to try to cause leaks.

I can narrow them down more, but it will take time. Is it usual to get these leaks, or should I comb through and find the root causes of them?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are possibly your leaks. Here would be one way of triggering the `UIColor` leak:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    [[UIColor allocWithZone:NULL] initWithWhite:1.0f alpha:1.0f];
```